# maven dependencies not found for custom maven project android

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

I have installed m2e eclipse plugin . i created a custom maven project but it does not show up maven dependencies and workspace has error . "dependency=[XXXXXXXXXXXX:shared:apklib:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile] not found in 
 workspace" . I have followed the following but nothing worked .

[m2eclipse not finding maven dependencies, artifacts not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393685/m2eclipse-not-finding-maven-dependencies-artifacts-not-found)

Wasting a lot of time because eclipse complains about missing classes during compilation .

Thanks !

Comment: I don't think [this company](http://shopsavvy.mobi/developers/) provide free SDK/API, if you have purchased and have got its apklib, using mvn install:install-file to manually install the apklib into your local maven repository.

Comment: No that is not the reason . mvn install works but just the depency does not show up in workspace

Comment: Do you have the m2android installed?

Comment: what is m2android ? link ? i have m2e android plugin installed for eclipse

Comment: Sorry.. I meant me2-android. Anyway.. make sure it is the latest version. http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/ apklib support is still in development